# How to use dataframe row value as pattern in sub or gsub

Tags: r

How to use sub or gsub to remove a certain string from the dataframe using the pattern which is an output of a column?

Example:
If a dataframe has "674-S00301:uO4_33_ControllerFailure:Slot0:50014385150"

and "674-S00301" is saved in a column named issue and check respectively; then how do we pass the value as pattern

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
    test$Actual <- sub(test$check[i],"", test[i,7))
}
```

`test[,7]` is "674-S00301:uO4_33_ControllerFailure:Slot0:50014385150"

Comment: You need `test$Actual[i]`

Comment: You could avoid loops and try this `test$Actual =  ifelse(unlist(strsplit(z,":"))[1]==test$check,paste(tail(unlist(strsplit(z,":")),-1),collapse=":"),z)`  where `z="674-S00301:uO4_33_ControllerFailure:Slot0:50014385150"`. It checks for equality of first part of string with check value, if match is found, remainder of string is the output else the orginal string